# win32com send email with multiple embedded image

Tags: python, html-email

```
outlook = win32com.client as win32
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

for j in range(list)
    file = "C:desktop\\image{}.png".format(j)
    attachment = mail.Attachments.Add(file)
    index = "ID{}".format(j)
    attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", index)

mail.HTMLBody = "<html><body> image <img src = ""cid:ID%s""></body></html>" % (j)

mail.Send()
```

The purpose is to embed all images (0,1,2,...maximum number defined by 'list') into the email. But now stuck at the for loop. May I know if there is any method can achieve this purpose? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After some intense research on the internet, I have found an answear to this particular problem. The solution was to import base64 and generate an image tag with it. I will post here my code so you can try it for yourself.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import base64

def send_email(subject, text, list_img_paths):

    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    myItem = outlook.CreateItem(0)

    myItem.Subject = subject
    list_email_img = []
    img_tag = ''
    for i in range(len(list_img_paths)):
        list_email_img.append(base64.b64encode(open(list_img_paths[i], 'rb').read()).decode('utf-8').replace('\n',''))
        img_tag +='<img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,{}"/>'.format(list_email_img[i])
    myItem.HtmlBody = """\
    <html>
    <head>{}</head>
    <body>
    <p>{}<br>
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
    """.format(text, img_tag)
    myItem.To = "example@company.com"
    myItem.CC = 'example@example.org'
    myItem.Display()
    myItem.Send()
```

Hope this can help